# How to initialize a static attribute in a generic class?

Tags: c#, templates

I've a problem in C# with a generic class:

```
class Hop<T>
{
     static string x;
}
```

Can I initialize `x` for all the instance of `Hop`?

Something like `Hop.x = "test";` doesn't work for instance.

Comment: I would highly recommend against a pattern like this; sharing data across all generic implementations is frowned upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, there is no `Hop` type, there is a `Hop<T>` generic type. How about:

```
class Hop
{
    static string X;
}

class Hop<T> : Hop
{

}
```

But the problem you still have, is this:

```
Hop<string>.X = "hello";
string x = Hop<int>.X; // x == "hello".
```

The static field is for the `Hop` type, not the `Hop<T>` type.

Comment: I think it's good for my needs, the "x" has to be the same for all the Hop<T>. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need compile-time initialization, you can write:

```
class Hop<T>
{
   static string x = "Foo";
}
```

For more complicated initialization, you can use a class initializer:

```
class Hop<T>
{
   static string x;

   static Hop()
   {
      x = "Foo";
   }
}
```